# Archiving part of Nexus repository

Tags: nexus

We have  old releases taking up needed disk space in Nexus. We very likely won't use these releases again but need to keep them for compliance reasons.

I would like to be able to move away some artefacts to a larger, slower storage location without:

1) confusing Nexus in any way (e.g. internal state, any metadata/DB etc.).
2) losing the ability to restore them later.

I don't think [the existing Nexus clean-up tasks](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465138-How-can-I-configure-Nexus-to-reduce-disk-space-) will achieve this, nor any of the [ad-hoc deletion scripts](https://github.com/akquinet/nexus_cleaner) I've seen (which seem to predate the tasks and/or deal with shortcomings).

Is there a good way to achieve this?

We are using Sonatype Nexus 2.11.3-01.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1) Since NXRM2 is on a file system, you should be able to write some sort of script to look at artifact age and then copy the artifacts away.  Then you could use the built in cleanup as normal.

2) While I haven't tried this/may be dangerous, if the scheduled tasks meet your needs for FINDING items but not for saving them, you could empty trash, run the tasks and then everything in the trash folder should be what you want to save.  Definitely make sure you don't have an auto delete trash or any other trash in there if going with this option.

Neither of these are built in, so are kind of hacking around but I think they'd work (without trying).